# CMake: Clean additional generated files

Tags: cmake

I'm creating a CMake project in which the linking command of my library produces an additional `.map` file (using the `-Wl,-Map=my-file.map` GCC option).

The file is properly created, but I'd like the resulting *clean* task to properly delete that file like it does for other generated ones.

So I'm trying to make CMake aware of this "new" file to be cleaned out.

It looks like combining [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/set_property.html#command:set_property) and [ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/prop_dir/ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES.html#prop_dir:ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES) is the solution but I cannot make it work properly.

```
set_property(
        DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        TARGET    my-target
        APPEND
        PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES my-file.map
)
```

Note that I also would like to make CMake know that this file is coming from the `my-target` target. That means this additional file should only be deleted when I clean the `my-target` target.

Moreover, I'd like to add other files to this clean list if necessary in the future (hence the `APPEND`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set_property` command requires you to choose *one* scope (`DIRECTORY` or `TARGET`), not both. Since you want to apply this property to the `my-target` target, use **only** the `TARGET` scope.

Also, the [`ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES.html) directory property is deprecated and should no longer be used. Instead, use the [`ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES.html#prop_tgt:ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES) target property here:

```
set_property(
        TARGET my-target
        APPEND
        PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES my-file.map
)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Actually, I completely missed the following `set_property` manual part: *The first argument determines the scope in which the property is set. It must be one of the following: [...]*. And I don't know how I could find the deprecated property instead of the good one.

Comment: You can also use:  `set_target_properties(my-target PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES my-file.map)`

Answer (score 1):

Your call to [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/set_property.html) is invalid. You can set either the directory property, or the target property, but not both at the same time.

You also used the wrong property name for some reason.

This code should correctly set [the relevant target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/prop_tgt/ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES.html) and works as expected with the Makefile generator for me:

```
set_property(
  TARGET my-target
  APPEND
  PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES my-file.map
)
```

Comment: Thank you too. As both your solution and the one of @squareskittles are valid, I validated the first one, sorry.